# How to implement navigation between UIViewControllers with forward and back transition in IOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

Let's say I have a list of articles I want to navigate through. With iOS 6 there were two simple solutions:

1. Using UIPageViewController
2. Using a custom solution with an UIScrollView, maybe a nested one

That's pretty straight forward but it lacks of flexibility regarding custom transitions. With UIPageViewController I only have two (Page Curl and Scroll), with UIScrollView there is only Scroll.

The transition effect I am looking for is the one introduced by Apple with iOS 7. The one we get by pushing a new controller to the stack, see the screenshot:

[image]

That comes with a really nice user experience in my opinion, but it only works the way back, not forward. But as the Safari browser supports also navigating in both directions, I am wondering how it is implemented there and, eventually, how I could implement it for my list of articles.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the exact same problem recently and built a [working demo](https://github.com/alfiehanssen/ios-viewcontroller-containment) that uses `UIViewController` containment and a subclass of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. It supports:

- Gesture-based paging in both directions (tracks touch rather than simply triggers animation on swipe)
- Ability to enable/disable wrapping (moving from page 0 to lastIndex and back)
- Ability to enable/disable parallax paging (when disabled you just get standard `UIScrollView` like paging

https://github.com/alfiehanssen/ios-viewcontroller-containment

An alternative would be to build a pager based on the new `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` and associated protocols.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Your demo looks nice, good job. However it's not as smooth as the native implementation Apple provides yet, so there is still some little work to do (after porting your code to C# ;)). For now I decided to go the straight forward way using the UIPageViewController, even if I have to go without the nice transitions :-/.

Comment: Thanks asp_net, I agree it's a little rough around the edges, thanks for the encouraging remarks though. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have a stack of views or view controllers within your own container view controller, and use a pan gesture recogniser to track the finger swipes, and translate this into altering the frame/center of the top view.

There are plenty of iOS Slide Menu projects in github that will probably show you how to do the pan gesture recogniser.